# How can I analyze morphological features of image regions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have to spread rice grains on a sheet and then find the average length of the rice grains spread. Any ideas how to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? What ideas do you have?

Comment: I don't see anything having to do with parallel processing in the question, so I'm removing that tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a good contrast between the background and the rice, you can follow a simple (though naive algorithm) recipe (I don't remember the commands in Matlab but it will be easy using the help)

1 - Threshold

2- Component Labeling

3- Get the length of each component (as pointed by @second) and use it to reckon the average size.

Comment: what if the grains are touching each other and they are not aligned in a straight manner.?

Comment: rice grains can be touching each other in any manner.......wats ur comment on that..

Comment: The link is now:
http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/getting-information-about-image-pixel-values-and-image-statistics.html

Answer (score 1):

This *exact* situation can be found as an image processing example in the online MathWorks documentation for the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/):

- [Example 2 — Analyzing Images](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/f0-8778.html)

Seriously, they use a picture of rice grains and everything! The only difference would be that you would want to look at a different property of the image when using the function [REGIONPROPS](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/regionprops.html), probably the [`'MajorAxisLength'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/regionprops.html#bqkf8jb) (which requires using the `labeled` matrix from the example).

Answer (score 0):

sounds like homework but here are some ideas

look at `regionprops` in the image processing toolbox.

there are a bunch of properties it can help you find, `'majoraxislength'` may be apropriate.